Countless Errors After 24.04 LTS Upgrade - Startup Disk Creator Does Not Run
I see I'm not the only one to put trust in the new 24.04 LTS version of Ubuntu Desktop where it gives countless syntax and other errors and does not complete the upgrade, then a warning that the system might not be stable or bootable. Having been prompted to upgrade, I did it through the prompt from Desktop 23.10 when the errors showed and, while I have not rebooted yet (it did not prompt to do so), many things, such as local dev websites, Wine applications, Perl and much more do not run. Much of the errors seems to involve Python which neither installs nor uninstalls without the same errors.
Apparently the Startup Disk Creator also does not run so I'm stuck without a way to fix it unless someone has a command line patch and can tell me how to apply it.
sudo do-release-upgrade finds no new version while sudo do-release-upgrade -d indicates that a reboot is needed first which I am hesitant to do without any live media to boot to should it crash. I was hoping that with the -d switch it would find a patch but I can't get that far.
I already tried (after sudo apt update) sudo apt upgrade, sudo apt --fix-broken, sudo apt full-upgrade, sudo apt autoremove and a few others, all of which result in errors similar to those below.
sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
876 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python3 (3.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.12...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of cubic
error running python rtupdate hook cubic
/usr/share/gdebi/GDebi/GDebiCli.py:159: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\S'
  c = findall("[[(](\S+)/\S+[])]", msg)[0].lower()
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins/externaltools/library.py:212: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\-'
  RE_KEY = re.compile('^([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_.\-]*)(\[([a-zA-Z_@]+)\])?$')
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins/snippets/substitutionparser.py:162: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\s'
  match = re.match('\\\\?%s\s*' % self.REG_GROUP, tokens)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of light-locker-settings
error running python rtupdate hook light-locker-settings
/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/alternative-toolbar/alttoolbar_plugins.py:171: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
  translation = re.sub('\(..\)', '', translation, flags=re.DOTALL)
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/AstrawebParser.py:64: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\/'
  url = re.split('(\/display[^"]*)', entry)[1]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/AstrawebParser.py:66: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\/'
  title = re.split('(\/display[^>]*)([^<]*)', entry)[2][1:].strip()
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/AstrawebParser.py:97: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\/'
  lyrics = re.split('(<font face=arial size=2>)(.*)(<\/font><br></td><td*)', result)[2]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/JetlyricsParser.py:50: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\.'
  m = re.search('<a href=\'(http://jetlyrics\.com/viewlyrics\.php\?id=[0-9]*)\'>', result)
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/JlyricParser.py:49: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\.'
  m = re.search('<div class=\'title\'><a href=\'(/artist/[^\.]*\.html)\'>', result)
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/TerraParser.py:39: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\w'
  pattern = re.compile("&(#?\w+?);")
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/WinampcnParser.py:87: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\['
  lrcplaintext = re.sub('\[.*?\]', '', lrcplaintext)
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/lyrics.py:44: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
  LYRIC_TITLE_STRIP=["\(live[^\)]*\)", "\(acoustic[^\)]*\)", "\([^\)]*mix\)", "\([^\)]*version\)", "\([^\)]*edit\)", "\(feat[^\)]*\)"]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/lyrics.py:44: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
  LYRIC_TITLE_STRIP=["\(live[^\)]*\)", "\(acoustic[^\)]*\)", "\([^\)]*mix\)", "\([^\)]*version\)", "\([^\)]*edit\)", "\(feat[^\)]*\)"]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/lyrics.py:44: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
  LYRIC_TITLE_STRIP=["\(live[^\)]*\)", "\(acoustic[^\)]*\)", "\([^\)]*mix\)", "\([^\)]*version\)", "\([^\)]*edit\)", "\(feat[^\)]*\)"]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/lyrics.py:44: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
  LYRIC_TITLE_STRIP=["\(live[^\)]*\)", "\(acoustic[^\)]*\)", "\([^\)]*mix\)", "\([^\)]*version\)", "\([^\)]*edit\)", "\(feat[^\)]*\)"]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/lyrics.py:44: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
  LYRIC_TITLE_STRIP=["\(live[^\)]*\)", "\(acoustic[^\)]*\)", "\([^\)]*mix\)", "\([^\)]*version\)", "\([^\)]*edit\)", "\(feat[^\)]*\)"]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rhythmbox/plugins/lyrics/lyrics.py:44: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
  LYRIC_TITLE_STRIP=["\(live[^\)]*\)", "\(acoustic[^\)]*\)", "\([^\)]*mix\)", "\([^\)]*version\)", "\([^\)]*edit\)", "\(feat[^\)]*\)"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of system-config-printer
error running python rtupdate hook system-config-printer
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-common:
 sssd-common depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-proxy:
 sssd-proxy depends on sssd-common (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-proxy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-click:
 python3-click depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-click (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-distupgrade:
 python3-distupgrade depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                                              No apport
 report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached
 already
        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                      No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                    yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-distupgrade (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-markupsafe:
 python3-markupsafe depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-markupsafe depends on python3 (>= 3.12~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-markupsafe depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-markupsafe (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-sss:
 python3-sss depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-sss depends on python3 (>= 3.12~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-sss depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                             python3-sss (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apport:
 apport depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apport (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-tz:
 python3-tz depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-tz (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            No apport report written be
cause MaxReports is reached already
                                   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-bs4:
 python3-bs4 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-bs4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-apport:
 python3-apport depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-apport (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of netplan.io:
 netplan.io depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package netplan.io (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-cupshelpers:
 python3-cupshelpers depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-cupshelpers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-serial:
 python3-serial depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-serial (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-common:
 grub-common depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ibus-table:
 ibus-table depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ibus-table (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-ipa:
 sssd-ipa depends on sssd-common (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-ipa (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-cups:amd64:
 python3-cups:amd64 depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-cups:amd64 depends on python3 (>= 3.12~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-cups:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-jinja2:
 python3-jinja2 depends on python3-markupsafe (>= 2.0); however:
  Package python3-markupsafe is not configured yet.
 python3-jinja2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-jinja2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pygments:
 python3-pygments depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-pygments (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-packaging:
 python3-packaging depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-packaging (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-chardet:
 python3-chardet depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-chardet (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of os-prober:
 os-prober depends on grub-common; however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package os-prober (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-configobj:
 python3-configobj depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-configobj (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-louis:
 python3-louis depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-louis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libglib2.0-dev:amd64:
 libglib2.0-dev:amd64 depends on python3 | qemu-user | qemu-user-static; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
  Package qemu-user is not installed.
  Package qemu-user-static is not installed.
 libglib2.0-dev:amd64 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-secretstorage:
 python3-secretstorage depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-secretstorage (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pyparsing:
 python3-pyparsing depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            dpkg: error processing pack
age python3-pyparsing (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgirepository1.0-dev:
 libgirepository1.0-dev depends on libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.80.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgirepository1.0-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-certifi:
 python3-certifi depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-certifi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bpfcc-tools:
 bpfcc-tools depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package bpfcc-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-ad-common:
 sssd-ad-common depends on sssd-common (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-ad-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of inkscape:
 inkscape depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package inkscape (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-krb5-common:
 sssd-krb5-common depends on sssd-common (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-krb5-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-extra-utils:
 texlive-extra-utils depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-extra-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pexpect:
 python3-pexpect depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-pexpect (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-cryptography:
 python3-cryptography depends on python3 (>= 3~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-cryptography depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-cryptography (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpango1.0-dev:amd64:
 libpango1.0-dev:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-dev; however:
  Package libglib2.0-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpango1.0-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-gi:
 python3-gi depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-gi depends on python3 (>= 3.12~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-gi depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-gi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-brlapi:amd64:
 python3-brlapi:amd64 depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-brlapi:amd64 depends on python3 (>= 3.12~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-brlapi:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-idna:
 python3-idna depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-idna (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-markdown:
 python3-markdown depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-markdown (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core depends on python3-distupgrade (= 1:24.04.18); however:
  Package python3-distupgrade is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgirepository-1.0-dev:amd64:
 libgirepository-1.0-dev:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.80.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.
    
dpkg: error processing package pkg-kde-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of jackd2:
 jackd2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package jackd2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems 

dpkg: error processing package python3-html5lib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-numpy:
 python3-numpy depends on python3 (<< 3.13); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-numpy depends on python3 (>= 3.12~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-numpy depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-numpy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 sssd-common
 sssd-proxy
 python3-click
 python3-distupgrade
 python3-markupsafe
 python3-sss
 apport
 python3-tz
 python3-bs4
 python3-apport
 netplan.io
 python3-cupshelpers
 python3-serial
 grub-common
 ibus-table
 sssd-ipa
 python3-cups:amd64
 python3-jinja2
 python3-pygments
 python3-packaging
 python3-chardet
 os-prober
 python3-configobj
 python3-louis
 libglib2.0-dev:amd64
 python3-secretstorage
 python3-pyparsing
 libgirepository1.0-dev
 python3-certifi
 bpfcc-tools
 sssd-ad-common
 inkscape
 sssd-krb5-common
 texlive-extra-utils
 python3-pexpect
 python3-cryptography
 libpango1.0-dev:amd64
 python3-gi
 python3-brlapi:amd64
 python3-idna
 python3-markdown
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
 libgirepository-1.0-dev:amd64
 python3-typing-extensions
 pkg-kde-tools
 jackd2
 python3-fasteners
 python3-html5lib
 python3-numpy
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


Get python3 running first.  Might be a chicken and egg problem, try dpkg --reconfigure python3.12

Yes, I suspected as much but tried countless things already to work around it. one of those was dpkg but it just gives an error: dpkg: error: unknown option --reconfigure. Trying dpkg: error: unknown option -reconfigure instead gives: dpkg: error: conflicting actions -e (--control) and -r (--remove)

Sorry, that should have been the dpkg-reconfigure command.

@ubfan1 I ran sudo dpkg-reconfigure python3.12 but not clear if anything happened as it simply and immediately returned to the command prompt. I also ran sudo apt install python3.12 but got the same, or similar, long series or errors that I posted in my question which ended with Processing was halted because there were too many errors.. I guess I should try to reboot and see what happens although odd that the upgrade did not prompt to do so.

You might try first reinstalling the three packages that cause the error (those giving "Exception: cannot get content of ..."), then retry.

On a general level;
Expecting numerous software packages, installed "on top of" the current OS, to be fully functional, automatically upgraded, after an OS update? [1]
I'd say; that is a futile wet dream (wording influenced by Swedish way to say that).
The simplest (most safe) option you have:
Backup your data - [X]
Get some kind of media to use.
Download the 24.04 ISO                  (e.g. use $ wget web/ftp-link)  [2]
Verify it                                             ($ sha256sum SHA256SUMS)
Create the install disk/media.          (e.g. use $ dd ...)  [3]
Install a clean 24.04
Setup your software
Install / import your backup data
... this due to the fact that the current state is unknown, somewhere in the midst of a conversion between OS versions.

[X] don't forget ~/.config and other dot files/folders.
To see them: Hold CTRL and hit H in "Files" (= $ nautilus) or $ ls -A in shell/terminal.
[1] This would require each of your additional packages to have a package-specific "upgrade to 24.04" option! The OS upgrade cannot / does not include this.
[2] https://releases.ubuntu.com/24.04/ -
https://releases.ubuntu.com/24.04/ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.iso
https://releases.ubuntu.com/24.04/SHA256SUMS
[3] sudo dd if=ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.iso bs=1M of=/dev/sda status=progress
(replace /sda with your local / actual disk name!)

After a 40 mile drive each way to fetch my old Ubuntu (23.10) laptop, I was able to make a boot USB stick and did a fresh install. Nothing else made any difference as, with whatever the problem was, I could not install or remove anything. A fresh install seemed the only way to solve the conundrum.
